# TCP/IP communication from the unix server to the Pure Data

Tags: unix, networking, client-server, puredata

I am interested in TCP/IP communication from the Unix server to the Pure Data. I have it realized using sockets on the Unix server side, and netclient on the Pure Data side. I exploited the chat-server tutorial for this (3.Networking > 10.chat_client.pd).

Now the problem lies that the server is streaming the data out as a "string" message delimited with ";"

**My question is, is there a way to send something other than string message to Pure Data, like byte-stream or serialized number stream? Can Pure Data receive such messages?**

Since string takes too many bytes to transfer, for example number "1024;" is already 5 bytes, while such an integer number is just 4 bytes.

UPDATE: For everyone that stumbles upon this post in search for the answer.

Apparently [netclient] on the Pure Data side cannot receive nothing else than ; delimited messages.
So the solution for the problem posed above:
**My question is, is there a way to send something other than string message to Pure Data, like byte-stream or serialized number stream? Can Pure Data receive such messages?**

The solution is to use [tcpclient], it can receive byte-stream data.

**Now my question is, how do I get four compact numbers to work with?**
Now I have a series of bytes, at least in the correct order.

From my UNIX server I am sending a structure

```
typedef struct {
    int     var_code;
    int    sample_time;
    int     hr;
    float    hs;
} phy_data;
```

Sample data might be 2 1000000 51 2000.56

When received and printed  in Pure Data I get output like this:

> > > : 0 0 0 2 0 10 114 26 0 0 0 51 0 16 242 78

You can notice number 2 and number 51 clearly, I guess the others are correct as well.

**How can I get these numbers back to a usable format?**
Maybe some manipulation with [bytes2any] and [route], but I haven't been able to extract the data with it?

Comment: the integer `1000000` should translate to `0 15 66 64` rather than `0 10 114 26` (which is 684570 if your byte ordering is big-endian (the default for network transmission)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's an outline of what you have to do:

- repackage the bytelist to small messages of the correct size for the various types.

  since all your elements are 4 byte long, you simply repackage your list (or bytestream, as TCP/IP doesn't guarantee to deliver your 16 bytes as a single list, but could also decide to break it into a list of arbitrary length) to a number of 4 atom lists.

  the most stable way, would probably be to 1st serialize the list (check the "serializer" example in the [list] help) and than reassamble that list to 4 elements.

  if you can use externals like zexy you could use [repack 4] for that.

  if you trust [netclient] to output your messages as complete lists, you could simply use a large [unpack ....] and 4 [pack]s
- interpret the raw data for each sublist

  integers is rather simple, floats are way more complicated

integers:

```
    |
    [unpack 0 0 0 0]
    |      |   |   |
    [<< 8] |   |   |
    |      |   |   |
    [+     ]   |   |
    |          |   |
    [<< 8]     |   |
    |          |   |
    [+         ]   |
    |              |
    [<< 8]         |
    |              |
    [+             ]
    |
```

floats are left as an exercise to the user :-)

Comment: for the impatient i posted a bytes2float patch in the [pd-list](http://lists.puredata.info/pipermail/pd-list/2013-03/101950.html)

Answer (score 0):

the real solution to your problem would be to use a well-defined application-layer protocol, rather than brew your own.

the most widespread protocol in use for applications like Pd, is certainly [OSC](http://opensoundcontrol.org).

in order to decode the raw OSC-bytes into Pd-messages, use [unpackOSC] (part of the "mrpeach" library; on Debian, you install it via the `pd-osc` package)

on the "server" side, you can use [liblo](http://liblo.sourceforge.net/) for encoding data and sending it.

### note

be aware that since OSC is packet-based, you will need a packetizing mechanism for stream-based protocols like TCP/IP. as with OSC-1.2, this should be [SLIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol). `liblo` should already take care of this. check the patches accompanying [unpackOSC] for how to do this within Pd.

all this is not needed if you are using a UDP as a transport.